# Values are not Updated after Updating the Value in Lightning-record-view-from

Tags: lightning-web-components

HTML

```
<lightning-record-view-form record-id={locationIdtoEdit} object-api-name="Location__c">
   <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="Location_Name__c"></lightning-output-field>
 </lightning-record-view-form>
```

Location_Name__c is Updated by at database  by code but the Value in html is not updated please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The [lightning-record-*-form components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_get_user_input) and [LWC wire services - lightning/uiRecordApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_record) are based on [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_ui_api).

> If a page is composed of components showing the same record, all
> components show the same version of the record. Records loaded in
> Lightning Data Service are cached and shared across components.
> Components accessing the same record see significant performance
> improvements, because a record is loaded once, no matter how many
> components are using it.
>
> If Lightning Data Service detects a change to a record or any data or
> metadata it supports, then all components using a relevant @wire
> receive the new value. The detection is triggered if:
>
> - A Lightning web component mutates the record
> - The LDS cache entry expires and then a Lightning web component’s @wire triggers a read. ***The cache entry and the Lightning web component must be in the same
>   browser and app (for example Lightning Experience) for the same user***
>
> To create and update data, use JavaScript functions exposed in the
> lightning/uiRecordApi module.
>
> Lightning Data Service does a lot of work to make code perform well.
>
> - Loads record data progressively.
> - ***Caches results on the client.***
> - Invalidates cache entries when dependent Salesforce data and metadata
>   changes.
> - Optimizes server calls by bulkifying and deduping requests.

Of the above documentation, the highlighted points are very important for your question in context. So, you will see the changes ONLY if you trigger the change from your machine.

**Solution:**

You can use [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) or [Platform events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm) to notify when record updated in database and subscribe for changes through [lightning:empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation)